# Дистанционная активация selectmenu JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Есть элемент стилизованный благодаря `selectmenu`, также есть кнопка в другой месте страницы (но в пределах видимости экрана относительно `selectmenu`, если это важно) Так вот, при клике на эту
кнопку должен раскрываться `selectmenu`. Как это реализовать?

---

P.S: Долго искал ответ в интернете, думая, что есть функция на подобии .click() в JQuery, которая активирует колбэк клика по элементу, но ничего не нашел(

---

P.S.S: Вообще если такой функции в JQuery UI нет, то подскажите пожалуйста как возможно реализовать мою задумку, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужна возможно выбирать какие-то значения в `<select>` (пусть даже кастомном), не только через его список, но и по кнопкам, которые будут находиться где-то на этой же странице?

Если да, то как сказал [@InDevX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1000691/221218)

Можно имитировать такое благодаря `.click()`, но а со стандартным `<select>` не стоит забывать и про атрибут `selected`.

Напишу небольшой скрипт, который будет выбирать в определённом селекторе определённые значения используя `data` атрибуты:

```js
$('[data-select]').on('click', function(){
  let select = $(this).data('select'),
      index = $(this).data('index');
  
  if(select && index)
    $('#'+select+' option').eq(index).click().prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectOne">
  <option selected>Ваш пол</option>
  <option>Мужской</option>
  <option>Женский</option>
</select>

<select id="selectTwo">
  <option selected>Ваш возраст</option>
  <option>&lt;18</option>
  <option>18-40</option>
  <option>&gt;40</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Я мужчина" data-select="selectOne" data-index="1">
<input type="button" value="Я женщина" data-select="selectOne" data-index="2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Мне 22" data-select="selectTwo" data-index="2">
<input type="button" value="Мне 47" data-select="selectTwo" data-index="3">
```

---

P.s.
`data-select` ищет элемент `<select>` по `id`,
`data-index` ищет в нём элемент `<option>` по индексу (от 0).

Всё это можно переписать под любые "входные идентификаторы".

---

Использование метода [`.selectmenu('open')`](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-open) можно управлять открытием списка

```
$('#myselect').selectmenu('open');
```

Пример, реализованный по тому же функционалу, что и выше:

```js
$("#CustomSelector")
  .selectmenu()
  .selectmenu("menuWidget")
  .addClass("overflow");
 
$('[data-select]').on('click', function(e){
  let id = $(this).data('select');
  $('#'+id).selectmenu('open');
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Открыть" data-select="CustomSelector">
<br><br>

<select name="number" id="CustomSelector">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected="selected">2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблема в том, что .selectmenu в JQuery UI скрывает изначальное меню select и стандартные способы взаимодействия с select не работают с selectmenu. Я попробую ваш вариант решения, но скорее всего он не поможет)

Comment: P.S: Я не хочу выбирать какой-либо вариант списка при раскрытии, мне надо что бы список просто раскрывался

Comment: @Cat_In_Ears, дополнил ответ реализацией конкретно под jQuery UI

Comment: помог, спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 1):

> P.S: Долго искал ответ в интернете, думая, что есть функция на подобии
>   .click() в JQuery, которая активирует колбэк клика по элементу, но
>   ничего не нашел(

```js
$('#two').hide().click(function(){
    alert('click');
});
$('#one').click(function(){
   $('#two').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="one">clickMe</button>
<button id="two">Hidden button with click alert</button>
```

`click()` имитирует нажание на эл-т в данном случае